# .htaccess redirect based on querystring

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just launched a new worpdress site which replaces an old asp site.

While google is re-indexing i've been asked to make sure that key pages get redirected.

For example:
www.egmont.co.uk/default.asp?pageid=3 needs to go to http://www.egmont.co.uk/who-we-are/what-we-do/books/

Googling has led me to construct the following, but it doesnt work, can anyone tell me why?:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pageid=3
RewriteRule /who-we-are/what-we-do/books/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close but remember that `RewriteRule` syntax is:

```
RewriteRule <pattern-to-match-in-uri> <target-uri> <flags>
```

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=3(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^default\.asp$ /who-we-are/what-we-do/books/? [L,R=302,NC]
```

- Make sure this rule is placed before other WP rewrite code.
- Once you verify it is working you can change `302` to `301`.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Nice explanation, +1. Out of curiosity, why do you use the `/` at the beginning of `/who`, is it a matter of your personal preference?

Comment: Usually If I use `R` flag then I explicitly use leading `/` as some Apache versions incorrectly fail without it.

Comment: Ha, I did not know that! And for the `L` flag, would you ever use a leading `/`?

Comment: When there is no `R` flag then we can omit leading `/` like this: `who-we-are/what-we-do/books/?`

Comment: Also it is safer to use `RewriteBase` in all the cases

Comment: Yes definitely on LHS leading slash cannot be matched in .htaccess (it is still needed if rule us in Apache config)

Comment: `Also it is safer to use RewriteBase in all the cases` I did not know that.